# google sheet date values refreshed with new locale

Tags: date, google-sheets

I noticed that dates in column be were interpreted as MM-DD-YYYY. I changed the google sheet settings to a locale that matches the format that I used DD-MM-YYYY. I also changed the recalculation of setting to "on change and every minute". I also have refreshed the page, however the date is not being reinterpreted as DD-MM-YYYY.

How do I force the dates in Column B to be reinterpreted with the new locale setting ?

Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: About `I noticed that dates in column be were interpreted as MM-DD-YYYY.`, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? In your expected result, you want to be forced to change all number formats of the date object to `DD-MM-YYYY`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly there's no automatic way to go from a string to a date. But you could create an auxiliary column to convert it to dates and then copy and paste. You could put this formula in the first row of that auxiliary column:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TO_TEXT(B:B)),B:B))
```

[image]

Then just copy and paste values, and if needed format again as date that column